# Управление чужими приложениями

Tags: c#, winapi

Есть старая программа, написанная на `Delphi`, исходников не осталось, в неё нужно каждый раз вводить пароль, как это можно сделать на `с#`, чтобы рукми не вводить? точнее вставлять текст в `textbox` и кликать по кнопке?

(так понимаю, нужно использовать `WinApi`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, наверное лучше использовать функции WinAPI. Тогда вам потребуется подключить следующую библиотечку - `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` и затем описываем библиотеку winapi из которой импортируем функцию (например)

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]   
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, string lParam);
```

Для обработки нажатия на кнопку можно посылать такое сообщение
WM_COMMAND, или WM_LBUTTONDOWN/WM_LBUTTONUP(левая кнопка мыши, для правой WM_RBUTTONDOWN/WM_RBUTTONUP)

А вообще если будете работать с WinAPI под .NET тогда вот вам незаменимый источник - [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/). Это сама настоящая кладезь инфы для разработчика в этом направлении, практически все функции WinAPI, их описание, можно просто скопировать их код к себе и все. Есть также плагин для Visual Studio, который позволяет работать с этим сайтом из среды (вставка котового кода импорта функций, просмотр/описание функций и тд.)

И еще как вариант решения вашей проблемы - если программа ваша, можно воспользоваться такими инструментами как IDA Pro, Dede и OllyDBG. При помощи декомпилятора Dede (он специально для делфей), найти адрес кода обработки нажатия на кнопку. Выяснить куда "прыгает" программа при вводе корректного пароля и в OllyDBG поправить переход на эту функцию, т.е. что бы мы не ввели, или вообще ничего не введем, будет все ОК. А чтоб и на кнопку не нажимать можно попробовать сделать вызов этой функции при запуске проги, т.е. в событии OnLoad вызывать эту функцию.

Comment: >> Выяснить куда "прыгает" программа при вводе корректного пароля и в OllyDBG поправить переход на эту функцию

особенно, если эта программа регистрируется в какой нибудь социальной сети, что бы читать сообщения :)

Тогда уже лучше с помощью редактора ресурсов просто форму поправить (это проще и легче) и вбить туда правильный пароль.